# How to delete public shared link of Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, cloud

I have a big folder in my Ubuntu One cloud, which I shared by creating public to one of my friend. Now I want to delete that link without deleting the folder from my Ubuntu One share folder. Can I do that ?

**Edited for image insert** --

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **Ubuntu One** and go to **Share links** tab. If you have something shared, a list with shared files will appear. **Double click** on the file that you want to remove from this shared list and you will see in the right side of the window a button named **Disable link**. Use it and after press 'Back to file list' link. Nothing will be deleted from your sync folders.

[image]

[image: Ubuntu one]

Comment: I don't have these option at my system. I have inserted snapshot of it...have a look...

Comment: Hmm... Try to update to a new version. Also, you shared those files from your current computer?

Comment: Yes I have shared it from current computer.

Comment: I double clicked on the files name & it was there.. Thanks :)